# Compiling OpenCV source code to Matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv, compilation

I am trying to compile a C++ code in Matlab. The source code uses the OpenCV library.
when I write:

> > mex myfile.cpp

I get the following Error:

> > fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' No such file or directory

I am using Matlab r2012b and have Visual c++ 2010 express on windows 7.

Is there please any solution for this?

Thank you.

Edit: I did the following but get another error:

```
 mex -v -largeArrayDims Calib.cpp -I"C:\opencv\build\include" ... 
-L"C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib"  -lopencv_calib3d240d -lopencv_core240d ... 
-lopencv_highgui240d -lopencv_imgproc240d -llibCam


->     Default options filename found in C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2012b 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
    ->    Options file           = C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2012b\mexopts.bat 
          MATLAB                 = C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2012b 
    ->    COMPILER               = cl 
    ->    Compiler flags: 
             COMPFLAGS           = /c /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD 
             OPTIMFLAGS          = /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG 
             DEBUGFLAGS          = /Z7 
             arguments           =  -IC:\opencv\build\include 
             Name switch         = /Fo 
    ->    Pre-linking commands   =  
    ->    LINKER                 = link 
    ->    Link directives: 
             LINKFLAGS           = /dll /export:mexFunction /LIBPATH:"C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win32\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib /MACHINE:X86 kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /nologo /manifest /incremental:NO /implib:"C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_LVNr2V\templib.x" /MAP:"Calib.mexw32.map" 
             LINKDEBUGFLAGS      = /debug /PDB:"Calib.mexw32.pdb" 
             LINKFLAGSPOST       =  
             Name directive      = /out:"Calib.mexw32" 
             File link directive =  
             Lib. link directive =  
             Rsp file indicator  = @ 
    ->    Resource Compiler      = rc /fo "mexversion.res" 
    ->    Resource Linker        =  
    ---------------------------------------------------------------- 


    --> cl  -IC:\opencv\build\include /c /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD /FoC:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_LVNr2V\Calib.obj -IC:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\include -IC:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2012b\simulink\include /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG Calib.cpp 

    Calib.cpp 
        Contents of C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_LVNr2V\mex_tmp.rsp: 
      C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_LVNr2V\Calib.obj 


    --> link /out:"Calib.mexw32" /dll /export:mexFunction /LIBPATH:"C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win32\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib /MACHINE:X86 kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /nologo /manifest /incremental:NO /implib:"C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_LVNr2V\templib.x" /MAP:"Calib.mexw32.map"  @C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_LVNr2V\mex_tmp.rsp  C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib\libCam.lib 
    C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_calib3d240d.lib C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_core240d.lib C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_highgui240d.lib C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib\opencv_imgproc240d.lib  

    LINK : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu mexFunction 
    C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_LVNr2V\templib.x : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externes non résolus 

      C:\PROGRA~3\MATLAB\R2012B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'Calib.mexw32' failed. 

    Error using mex (line 206)
    Unable to complete successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add include flags and linking libraries to the command line. That is,

`mex myfile.cpp -I header_path -l opencv_libraries`

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
mex -largeArrayDims Calib.cpp -IC:\opencv\build\include -LC:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib...
 -l opencv_calib3d240d -l opencv_core240d -l opencv_highgui240d -l opencv_imgproc240d
```

BTW, is there a special reason why you link with the opencv_< >**d**.lib rather than opencv_< >.lib files?

Comment: I got the following:

LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 

C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_REFPaa\templib.x : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externes not resolved

 C:\PROGRA~3\MATLAB\R2012B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'Calib.mexw32' failed. 
 
Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.

Comment: can you please `mex -v` to get a more verbosed output? can you read from the output what is the external symbol that is missing? Are you trying to include or link to other libraries or code? Is this error **different** than the `cannot open file` you reported earlier?

Comment: yes, this error is different than the 'cannot open file' I reported earlier. I am using one more header file and library in addition to opencv. I put the library file and header inside opencv directories

Comment: can you please `mex -v` and post more detailed errors regarding the missing symbols?

Comment: I posted in the first message the screen I get after taping `mex -v`

Comment: Your missing symbol is `mexFunction` - this is the main entry for any mex function in matlab. Are you familiar with writing mex functions in C/C++ to be used in matlab? see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html for more details.